# Angular and Typescript explicit module registration or not

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm using typescript and angular for an application and I noticed that even if I don't use `angular.module("x").controler('app.controllername',app.controllername);`  the controller does get register, but it goes to window.app.controllername and angular can find it and the controller is normally loaded to any view that uses it.

is there a problem using this approach ?  having it register "automagically" this way?

thanks

Comment: Is your controller defined inside your HTML view as [`ng-controller`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)?

Comment: Can you supply a bit more code?

Comment: Yes, controller is defined here <div data-ng-controller="myApp2.controllers.dashboard as vm">  and here

module myApp2.controllers {

    export class dashboard extends ControllerBase {

        public static $inject: string[] =
        [AppGlobal.NGSCOPE, AppGlobal.NGHTTP];

        private testVariable2: string = "This is a string from dashboard";

        constructor($scope: ng.IScope, $http: ng.IHttpService) {
            super(arguments, dashboard.$inject)

        }

    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automagically it only works because angular looks at `window.YourController`. It is definitely not recommended because:

- breaks in minification
- breaks in testing (you are exporting to `window`)
- breaks in AMD (TypeScript external module) scenarios as using external modules will take it off of `window` and put it in its own per file module.

Comment: Yes, controller is defined here <div data-ng-controller="myApp2.controllers.dashboard as vm">  and here

myApp2.controllers {

    export class dashboard extends ControllerBase {

        public static $inject: string[] =
        [AppGlobal.NGSCOPE, AppGlobal.NGHTTP];

        private testVariable2: string = "This is a string from dashboard";

        constructor($scope: ng.IScope, $http: ng.IHttpService) {
            super(arguments, dashboard.$inject)

        }

    }
}

Answer (score 1):

this problem faced by me and after searching for hours i found that the sequence in which my ts file was compiled was not proper , keep in note that the sequence should be

```
var app=angular.module('foo',[]);
 //after that controller lies

//and after that here the registering of conrtollers and services
 app.controllers('controller module name here');
 app.services('services module name here');
```